# Infeasable solution for transportation problem using gurobi python

Tags: python, modeling, gurobi, transport

For my study I have to make some exercises and I am getting stuck on a specific question. Here is the introduction to the exercise:

Introduction
The flower-cutting company “Blossom Logistics” specializes in the transportation of fresh flow-
ers. Blossom Logistics operates a network comprising fields, warehouses, and retailers. Within
their network, they handle three distinct categories of flowers: romantic roses (R), vibrant
tulips (T), and delicate lilies (L). They transfer the flower in boxes. The company faces in-
creasing competition during the flowering season, so optimizing its network has become crucial.
As an intern in Blossom Logistics’ operations department, you have received two data files:
“nodes.txt” and “fixedCost.txt”. The “nodes.txt” file contains essential information about each
node’s location, supply, and demand for each flower category. Meanwhile, the “fixedCost.txt”
file includes the fixed charges associated with utilizing different transportation routes between
the nodes. The network is represented by a directed graph, denoted as G = (V, A), and can
be visualized in Figure 1. Here, V represents the set of all nodes, and A represents the set of
all possible arcs.
In the “nodes.txt” file, the column “StringID” denotes the unique identifier for each node.
The nodes are categorized as follows: “f” for fields, “w” for warehouses, and “r” for retailers.
The columns “x” and “y” represent the coordinates of each node. Additionally, the columns
“capR”, “capT”, and “capL” denote the capacity of each node for romantic roses, vibrant
tulips, and delicate lilies, respectively. The columns “demR”, “demT”, and “demL” represent
the demand of each node for romantic roses, vibrant tulips, and delicate lilies, respectively.

Here is the nodes.txt:
StringID     x            y            capR         capT         capL         demR         demT         demL
f1           6            8            55           100          55           0            0            0
f2           7            27           55           115          150          0            0            0
w3           -8           13           0            0            0            0            0            0
w4           12           -23          0            0            0            0            0            0
w5           27           8            0            0            0            0            0            0
w6           -6           28           0            0            0            0            0            0
w7           3            -15          0            0            0            0            0            0
r8           -29          -27          0            0            0            40           70           70
r9           20           7            0            0            0            25           95           75
r10          -12          25           0            0            0            45           50           60

Transportation cost per kilometer for a box of R flower: 2
Transportation cost per kilometer for a box of T flower: 3
Transportation cost per kilometer for a box of L flower: 4

Below I provided pictures of the particular part I have troubles with:
[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOFaR.png) [Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzCAx.png)

So I have to code the model in python using Gurobi. The problem is is that I keep getting and infeasible solution. The code I have for now:

```
Aria Dahimi
import gurobipy as gp
import numpy as np

1) Read the data and define the problem

instname = 'nodes'

mainFolderInput   = 'C:\\Users\\karsp\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\'

mainFolderResults = 'C:\\Users\\karsp\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\'

fileAddress = mainFolderInput + instname + '.txt'


f = open(fileAddress)
nodeCount = 0
requestCount = 1
costFactor = 0
fDict = {}
rDict = {}
wDict = {}

for line in f.readlines()[1:-4]:

    asList = []

    n = 13

    for index in range(0, len(line)-1, n):

        if index == 0:

            asList.append(line[index : index + n].strip())

        else:

            asList.append(int(line[index : index + n].strip()))

    lID = asList[0]

    if lID.startswith("f"): 

        fDict[lID] = asList

    if lID.startswith("r"): 

        rDict[lID] = asList

    if lID.startswith("w"): 

       wDict[lID] = asList

    

vDict = {}
vDict.update(fDict)
vDict.update(rDict)
vDict.update(wDict)

print(fDict)

print()

print(rDict)

    print()

print(wDict)

print()

print(vDict)

​

    f = open(fileAddress)

capLine = f.readlines()[-1]

costFactor = int(capLine[-5:].strip())

​

print(costFactor)

{'f1': ['f1', 6, 8, 55, 100, 55, 0, 0, 0], 'f2': ['f2', 7, 27, 55, 115, 150, 0, 0, 0]}

{'r8': ['r8', -29, -27, 0, 0, 0, 40, 70, 70], 'r9': ['r9', 20, 7, 0, 0, 0, 25, 95, 75], 'r10': ['r10', -12, 25, 0, 0, 0, 45, 50, 60]}

{'w3': ['w3', -8, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'w4': ['w4', 12, -23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'w5': ['w5', 27, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'w6': ['w6', -6, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'w7': ['w7', 3, -15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

{'f1': ['f1', 6, 8, 55, 100, 55, 0, 0, 0], 'f2': ['f2', 7, 27, 55, 115, 150, 0, 0, 0], 'r8': ['r8', -29, -27, 0, 0, 0, 40, 70, 70], 'r9': ['r9', 20, 7, 0, 0, 0, 25, 95, 75], 'r10': ['r10', -12, 25, 0, 0, 0, 45, 50, 60], 'w3': ['w3', -8, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'w4': ['w4', 12, -23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'w5': ['w5', 27, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'w6': ['w6', -6, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'w7': ['w7', 3, -15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
4

transportCosts = {(i, j): costFactor * np.math.trunc(np.hypot(fDict[i][1]-wDict[j][1], fDict[i][2]-wDict[j][2])) for i in list(fDict.keys()) for j in list(wDict.keys())}

transportCosts2 = {(i, j): costFactor * np.math.trunc(np.hypot(wDict[i][1]-rDict[j][1], wDict[i][2]-rDict[j][2])) for i in list(wDict.keys()) for j in list(rDict.keys())}

transportCosts3 = {(i, j): costFactor * np.math.trunc(np.hypot(wDict[i][1]-wDict[j][1], wDict[i][2]-wDict[j][2])) for i in list(wDict.keys()) for j in list(wDict.keys())}

transportCosts.update(transportCosts2)

transportCosts.update(transportCosts3)

​

transportCosts

{('f1', 'w3'): 56,
 ('f1', 'w4'): 124,
 ('f1', 'w5'): 84,
 ('f1', 'w6'): 92,
 ('f1', 'w7'): 92,
 ('f2', 'w3'): 80,
 ('f2', 'w4'): 200,
 ('f2', 'w5'): 108,
 ('f2', 'w6'): 52,
 ('f2', 'w7'): 168,
 ('w3', 'r8'): 180,
 ('w3', 'r9'): 112,
 ('w3', 'r10'): 48,
 ('w4', 'r8'): 164,
 ('w4', 'r9'): 124,
 ('w4', 'r10'): 212,
 ('w5', 'r8'): 264,
 ('w5', 'r9'): 28,
 ('w5', 'r10'): 168,
 ('w6', 'r8'): 236,
 ('w6', 'r9'): 132,
 ('w6', 'r10'): 24,
 ('w7', 'r8'): 136,
 ('w7', 'r9'): 108,
 ('w7', 'r10'): 168,
 ('w3', 'w3'): 0,
 ('w3', 'w4'): 164,
 ('w3', 'w5'): 140,
 ('w3', 'w6'): 60,
 ('w3', 'w7'): 120,
 ('w4', 'w3'): 164,
 ('w4', 'w4'): 0,
 ('w4', 'w5'): 136,
 ('w4', 'w6'): 216,
 ('w4', 'w7'): 48,
 ('w5', 'w3'): 140,
 ('w5', 'w4'): 136,
 ('w5', 'w5'): 0,
 ('w5', 'w6'): 152,
 ('w5', 'w7'): 132,
 ('w6', 'w3'): 60,
 ('w6', 'w4'): 216,
 ('w6', 'w5'): 152,
 ('w6', 'w6'): 0,
 ('w6', 'w7'): 172,
 ('w7', 'w3'): 120,
 ('w7', 'w4'): 48,
 ('w7', 'w5'): 132,
 ('w7', 'w6'): 172,
 ('w7', 'w7'): 0}

2) initialize the model

TPModel = gp.Model('1CK100-TP')

Set parameter Username
Academic license - for non-commercial use only - expires 2024-06-01

TPModel.modelSense = gp.GRB.MINIMIZE

3) Variables

arcs = [('f1','w3'),('f1','w4'),('f2', 'w4'),('f2','w5'),('w3','w6'),('w4','w6'),('w4','r9'),('w4','w7'),('w5','w7'),('w5','r9'),('w6','r8'),('w6','r9'),('w6','r10'),('w7','r8'),('w7','r9'),('w7','r10')]

x = TPModel.addVars(arcs, vtype=gp.GRB.INTEGER, name='x')

x

{('f1', 'w3'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('f1', 'w4'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('f2', 'w4'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('f2', 'w5'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w3', 'w6'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w4', 'w6'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w4', 'r9'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w4', 'w7'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w5', 'w7'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w5', 'r9'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w6', 'r8'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w6', 'r9'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w6', 'r10'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w7', 'r8'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w7', 'r9'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>,
 ('w7', 'r10'): <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>}

3) Objective function

TPModel.setObjective(

    gp.quicksum(transportCosts[i, j] * x[i, j] for i, j in arcs)

)

4) Constraints
Capacity of warehouses

v = vDict.keys()

FirstConstraint = TPModel.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(x[i, j] for j in v if (i, j) in arcs) - gp.quicksum(x[j, i] for j in v if (j, i) in arcs) == fDict[i][5] for i in fDict.keys()), name='balance_f')

v = vDict.keys()

SecondConstraint = TPModel.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(x[i, j] for j in v if (i, j) in arcs) - gp.quicksum(x[j, i] for j in v if (j, i) in arcs) == (-1 * rDict[i][8]) for i in rDict.keys()), name='balance_r')

v = vDict.keys()

ThirdConstraint = TPModel.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(x[i, j] for j in v if (i, j) in arcs) - gp.quicksum(x[j, i] for j in v if (j, i) in arcs) == 0 for i in wDict.keys()), name='balance_w')

FourthConstraint = TPModel.addConstrs((x[i, j] >= 0 for i, j in arcs), name='nonnegativity')
```

Does anyone know why my model is infeasible and if so how do I correct it?

Comment: Why not try computeIIS or feasRelax?

Comment: Because we have to use gurobi.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: computeIIS and feasRelax are Gurobi features, see https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/py_model_computeiis.html  and https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/py_model_feasrelax.html